# Install qiskit on MacOS HighSierra Error: No such file or directory: 'qiskit.egg-info'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, qiskit

I was trying to install QISKit via the pip method as mentioned on [their webpage](https://www.qiskit.org/documentation/install.html).

However, after many trials, this method doesn't seem to work and I am getting the following error on the terminal.

```
  Compiling QISKit C++ Simulator
  creating out
  WARNING: Seems like the cpp simulator can't be built, Qiskit will install anyway, but won't have this simulator support.
  installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

  running install_egg_info
  Copying qiskit.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/wheel/qiskit-0.4.9.data/purelib/qiskit-0.4.9-py3.5.egg-info
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'qiskit.egg-info'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for qiskit (*)
  Running setup.py clean for qiskit
Failed to build qiskit 
Installing collected packages: Sphinx, qiskit
  Found existing installation: Sphinx 1.4.6
Cannot remove entries from nonexistent file /Users/photon/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/easy-install.pth (*)
```

where the lines ending with (*) are in red in the terminal.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to install cmake.

```
pip install cmake
```

I also had an issue with the latest QISKit. Kindly check the issue at the github page [QIS Issue 292](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-sdk-py/issues/292).